# $\sup_{t \in [0, \infty)} \left|[(H^{(n)} - H) \cdot X, Y]_t \right| \overset{P}{\rightarrow} 0$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, quadratic-variation

***1. Notation***

We start with establishing some (standard, I think) notation.

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ be a given probability space.

For any filtration $\mathcal{G} = (\mathcal{G}_t)_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ of $\mathcal{A}$, denote by $CM^{\text{loc}}(\mathcal{G})$ the set of continuous local martingales $(Z_t)_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ w.r.t. the filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P; \mathcal{G})$, and denote by $CM^2(\mathcal{G})$ the set of continuous martingales $(Z_t)_{t \in [0, \infty)}$ w.r.t. said filtered probability space, such that $|||Z|||_2 := \sup_{t \in [0, \infty)} \|Z_t\|_2 = \sup_{t \in [0, \infty)} \sqrt{E(Z_t^2)} < \infty$.

Define $|||Z|||_\infty := \sup_{(t, \omega) \in [0, \infty) \times \Omega} |Z_t(\omega)|$ and denote by $T(\mathcal{G})$ the set of $\mathcal{G}$-adapted stochastic processes, whose paths are step-functions, and by $\overline{T}(\mathcal{G})$ the set of $\mathcal{G}$-adapted stochastic processes $H$, such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |||H^{(n)} - H|||_\infty = 0$ for some sequence $H^{(1)}, H^{(2)}, \dots \in T(\mathcal{G})$.

Define $\mathcal{G}_\infty := \sigma\left(\bigcup_{t \in [0, \infty)} \mathcal{G}_t\right)$ and denote by $\overline{\mathcal{G}} = (\overline{\mathcal{G}}_t)_{t \in [0, \infty)}$ the completion of the filtration $\mathcal{G}$, i.e. $\overline{\mathcal{G}}_t := \sigma(\mathcal{G}_t \cup \{B \in \mathcal{G}_\infty \mid: P(B) = 0\})$.

Let $\mathcal{F} = (\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \in [0, \infty)}$ be some given filtration of the space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$.

If $X, Y \in CM^{\text{loc}}(\mathcal{F})$, we denote by $X \cdot Y = (X \cdot Y)_{t \in [0, \infty)}$ the stochastic integral
$$
(X \cdot Y)_t = \int_0^t X\ dY
$$

We define *the compensator* of $X$ and $Y$ by $[X, Y]$, thus:
$$
[X, Y] := XY - X_0Y_0 - X \cdot Y - Y \cdot X
$$
and we define the *quadratic variation* of $X$ thus:
$$
[X] := [X, X]
$$

It can be shown that $[X, Y]$ is a continuous, $\overline{\mathcal{F}}$-adapted stochastic process with $[X, Y]_0 = 0$, and that $[X]$'s paths are non-decreasing. We may therefore define
$$
[X]_\infty := \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} [X]_t
$$

---

***2. Statement of the problem***

The following claim ($(*)$ below) came up in a proof of the so called "fundamental identity of stochastic integration" (i.e. "If $H \in \overline{T}(\mathcal{F})$ and if $X, Y \in CM^{\text{loc}}(\mathcal{F})$, then $[H \cdot X, Y] = H \cdot [X, Y]$.") found in Jochen Wengenroth's German textbook on stochastic processes, "Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie", de Gruyter 2008, on p. 184.

Let $X, Y \in CM^2(\mathcal{F})$ be such that $X_0 = Y_0 = 0$. Let $H \in \overline{T}(\mathcal{F})$ and let $H^{(1)}, H^{(2)}, \dots \in T(\mathcal{F})$ be such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |||H^{(n)} - H|||_\infty = 0$.

It is known that under these circumstances the sequence of stochastic integrals $(H^{(n)} \cdot X)_{n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}}$ converges in $CM^2(\overline{\mathcal{F}})$ (to $H \cdot X$, by definition).

Then

$$
\sup_{t \in [0, \infty)} \left|[(H^{(n)} - H) \cdot X, Y]_t \right| \overset{P}{\rightarrow} 0 \tag{*}
$$

---

***3. Hints***

Wengenroth suggests that $(*)$ can be justified using the following two facts, proved earlier in the book.

1. Whenever $X^{(1)}, X^{(2)}, \dots \in CM^{\text{loc}}(\mathcal{F})$, we have:
   $$
   [X^{(n)}]_\infty \overset{P}{\rightarrow} 0 \iff \hat{X}^{(n)} := \sup_{t \in [0, \infty)} \left|X^{(n)}_t - X^{(n)}_0\right| \overset{P}{\rightarrow} 0
   $$
2. *The polarization identity*: Whenever $X, Y \in CM^{\text{loc}}(\mathcal{F})$ we have
   $$
   [X, Y] = \frac{1}{4} \left([X + Y] - [X - Y]\right)
   $$

---

***4. My attempts at a solution***

I'm aware that it is frowned upon in this forum to present a question without indicating the attempts made at solving it. Unfortunately, I'm at a loss and have no clue how to go about solving this problem. If any of you would be kind enough to point me in the right direction, I'll make an attempt to solve the problem based on your suggestions, and, if successful, I'll publish my results in an answer below. Alternatively, if you wish to provide a detailed answer to this problem, I'll be very grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to ask this on MathOverflow.

Comment: @Math1000: I wasn't aware there was a MathOverflow. What's the distinction between the present forum and MathOverflow?

Comment: MathOverflow is intended for research-level mathematics. This question looks sufficiently advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the following well-known theorem:

> Let $B$ be a bilinear form (on some $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $X$) such that $B(x,y) = B(y,x)$ and $B(x,x) \geq 0$ for any $x,y \in X$. Then $$|B(x,y)| \leq \sqrt{B(x,x)} \sqrt{B(y,y)} \qquad \text{for all $x,y \in X$}.$$

Applying this to the bilinear form $B(X,Y) := [X,Y]_t$ gives

$$|[X,Y]_t| \leq \sqrt{[X]_t} \sqrt{[Y]_t}$$

for any two continous local martingales $X,Y$. This implies

$$\sup_t |[(H^n-H) \cdot X,Y]_t| \leq \sqrt{[(H^n-H) \cdot X]_{\infty}} \sqrt{[Y]_{\infty}} \tag{1} $$

On the other hand, it is well-known that

$$[(H^n-H) \cdot X]_{\infty} = \int_0^{\infty} (H^n-H)^2(s) \, d[X]_s. \tag{2}$$

Consequently,

$$\sup_t |[(H^n-H) \cdot X,Y]_t| \leq \sqrt{\|H^n-H\|^2_{\infty} [X]_{\infty}} \sqrt{[Y]_{\infty}}.$$

Since $\|H^n-H\|_{\infty} \to 0$ by assumption, the claim follows.

**Edit: (Alternative argumentation which does not require $(2)$)** By $(1)$, it suffices to show that

$$[(H_n-H) \cdot X]_{\infty} \stackrel{P}{\to} 0. $$

Using the second hint (mentioned in the OP), we find that this is equivalent to

$$\sup_{t \in [0,\infty)} |(H_n-H) \cdot X_t| \stackrel{P}{\to} 0. \tag{3}$$

In order to prove $(3)$, we note that, by Doob's inequality,

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \sup_{t \leq T} |(H_n-H) \cdot X_t|^2 \right) \leq 4 \sup_{t \leq T} \mathbb{E}(|(H_n-H) \cdot X_t|^2)$$

and therefore

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \sup_{t \geq 0} |(H_n-H) \cdot X_t|^2 \right) \leq 4 \|\|(H_n-H) \cdot X\|\|_2^2.$$

As $H^n \cdot X$ converges in $CM^2(\bar{\mathcal{F}})$ to $H \cdot X$, we get

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E} \left( \sup_{t \geq 0} |(H_n-H) \cdot X_t|^2 \right) = 0.$$

Since $L^2$-convergence implies convergence in probability, $(3)$ follows.

Comment: Thank you very much for reading my long post and for answering it. There are a couple points in your answer that are unclear to me. (1) Why does the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality hold?, (2) It has not yet been proved in the book that $[(H^n - H) \cdot X]_\infty = \int_0^\infty (H^n - H)^2(s)\ d[X]_s$. Is there an alternative way of showing that $[(H^n - H) \cdot X]_\infty \leq \|H^n - H\|^2_\infty [X]_\infty$, possibly using Wengenroth's hints?

Comment: Thanks. BTW if it is of any help it may be assumed that $V_{[X,Y]} \leq N$ for some real $N > 0$. ($V_{[X, Y]} = \left((V_{[X, Y]})_t\right)_{t \in [0, \infty)}$ is the total variation of $[X, Y]$).

Comment: @EvanAad See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you. Shouldn't the right hand side of Doob's inequality should be $4 \mathbb{E}(|(H_n-H) \cdot X_T|^2)$? Also, did you mean the right-hand side of the inequality following Doob's inequality to be $4|||(H_n-H) \cdot X|||_2^2$ by any chance?

Comment: @EvanAad The square was missing, you are right. Since $$\mathbb{E}(|(H_n-H) \cdot X_T|^2) = \sup_{t \leq T} \mathbb{E}(|(H_n-H) \cdot X_t|^2)$$ it doesn't matter which bound we use.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'd like to add the following clarifications for my own future reference. (1) The Cauchy-Schwartz inequality for symmetric, non-negative definite bilinear forms is Theorem 4 on pp. 248 of Siegfried Bosch's "Lineare Algebra", 4th edition, Springer 2008 (in German). (2) Doob's inequality is theorem 8.4.2 on p. 156 in Wengenroth's textbook. (3) If $H \in \overline{T}(\mathcal{F})$ and $X \in CM^2(\mathcal{F})$, then $H \cdot X \in CM^2(\overline{\mathcal{F}})$. This is essentially by definition: see p. 179 in Wengenroth's textbook, as well as theorem 9.4.2 on p. 177.